# Multiple filters as input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to implement two filters in shiny. One is equal and other is in-string.
Equal filter works but the in-string filter is not working. The in-string filter is the one when the input value is present in a text column of the data table. Option to check multiple input value to check against the text column is needed.
Short example to replicate the issue is provided below:

```
v_lst_packages <- c("data.table",'shinydashboard','shiny')
a = lapply(v_lst_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

dt_src_tbl <- data.table(Col1=c('Apple','Mango','Pinapple'),
           Col2=c('Flt1','Flt1','Flt2'),
           Col3=c(',a,b,c',',a',',b'))

v_lst_col3 = c('a','b','c')
ui <- fluidPage(
    # display simple equal filter
    selectInput("par_col2", "Col2", dt_src_tbl %>% pull(Col2)),
    textOutput("par_col2_op"),
    tableOutput("dt_src_tbl2_op"),
    #------------------------
    # display subbstring filter
    selectInput("par_col3", "Col3", v_lst_col3, multiple = T),
    textOutput("par_col3_op"),
    tableOutput("dt_src_tbl3_op"),
    #-------------------------
    #display equal and substring filter
    tableOutput("dt_src_tbl_fnl_op")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Filtering data with equal filter
    output$dt_src_tbl2_op <- renderTable(
        dt_src_tbl %>%
            filter(Col2 == req(input$par_col2)) 
    )
    output$par_col2_op <- renderText(input$par_col2)
    #---------------------------------------
    #Filtering data with substring filter
    dt_src_tbl3 <- reactive( dt_src_tbl %>%
                               filter(grepl(req(input$par_col3)), Col3))
    output$dt_src_tbl3_op <- renderTable(dt_src_tbl3())
    output$par_col3_op <- renderText(input$par_col3)
    #---------------------------------------
    # Filtering data with equal ane substring filters
    dt_src_tbl_fnl <- reactive( dt_src_tbl %>%
                                 filter(grepl(req(input$par_col2)), Col2) %>% 
                                    filter(grepl(req(input$par_col3)), Col3))
    output$dt_src_tbl_fnl_op <- renderTable(dt_src_tbl_fnl())
}

shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Comment: misplaced `)`.  Try this `dt_src_tbl3 <- reactive( dt_src_tbl %>% dplyr::filter(grepl(req(input$par_col3), Col3)) )`

Comment: Thanks @YBS.The filter is working now. But the multi input is not working as needed.

Comment: Only the first element is taken to filter and the other elements are ignored kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `grepl()` gives logical output `(TRUE, FALSE)`, you can pick the corresponding rows directly from the data frame. There is no need to filter.  Try this

```
v_lst_packages <- c("data.table",'shinydashboard','shiny')
a = lapply(v_lst_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

dt_src_tbl <- data.table(Col1=c('Apple','Mango','Pinapple'),
                         Col2=c('Flt1','Flt1','Flt2'),
                         Col3=c(',a,b,c',',a',',b'))

v_lst_col3 = c('a','b','c')
ui <- fluidPage(
  # display simple equal filter
  selectInput("par_col2", "Col2", dt_src_tbl %>% pull(Col2)),
  textOutput("par_col2_op"),
  tableOutput("dt_src_tbl2_op"),
  #------------------------
  # display subbstring filter
  selectInput("par_col3", "Col3", v_lst_col3, multiple = T),
  textOutput("par_col3_op"),
  tableOutput("dt_src_tbl3_op"),
  #-------------------------
  #display equal and substring filter
  tableOutput("dt_src_tbl_fnl_op")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Filtering data with equal filter
  output$dt_src_tbl2_op <- renderTable(
    dt_src_tbl %>%
      dplyr::filter(Col2 == req(input$par_col2))
  )
  output$par_col2_op <- renderText(input$par_col2)
  #---------------------------------------
  #Filtering data with substring filter
  dt_src_tbl3 <- reactive( dt_src_tbl[grepl(req(input$par_col3), Col3 ),] )
  output$dt_src_tbl3_op <- renderTable(dt_src_tbl3())
  output$par_col3_op <- renderText(input$par_col3)
  #---------------------------------------
  # Filtering data with equal and substring filters
  dt_src_tbl_fnl <- reactive( dt_src_tbl[grepl(req(input$par_col3), Col3 ),] %>%
                                dplyr::filter(Col2 == req(input$par_col2)) # %>%
                                # dplyr::filter(grepl(Col3, req(input$par_col3) )) 
                              )
  output$dt_src_tbl_fnl_op <- renderTable(dt_src_tbl_fnl())
}

shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks YBS...I could get the help from your comment on dplyr::filter. Subsequently I used the | to compare multiple values. Thanks once again.